# How to code a transaction between sellers and buyers on the same patch?

Tags: netlogo

I have to code a SELLERS-BUYERS model in Netlogo. And some parts of it I have already done.
But there some troubles with calculating of "deal price" and some other processes. 
The problem is that I dont know the programm language of Netlogo so well that to code all of the model.

I have to settle a deal_Price between seller and buyer and they have to be in one patch. Every seller has its ownCosts and every buyer has its ownUtility. When the seller_Price = buyer_Price they have deal_Price. And this deal_Price has to be below ownUtility of the buyer and above of ownCosts of the seller (which are in the same patch).  And all of this happens in "interaction" process.

i code it so:

```
    to interaction

      ask sellers [
       set seller_Price 0]

      ask buyers [
      set buyer_Price 0]

      ask buyers [ 
         if buyer_Price > ownUtility [
         set buyer_Price buyer_Price < ownUtility ]]

      ask sellers [
         if seller_Price < ownCosts [
         set seller_Price seller_Price > ownCosts ]]
end
```

For the result buyer and seller ( who are in the same patch) have to deal. And I tried to code "deal" process so:

```
to deal 

  if thera buyer and seller in one patch (its probably false)

  ask buyers [
     set ownUtility ownUtility + (buyer_Price - deal_Price)]
  ask sellers [
     set ownCosts ownCosts + (seller_Price - deal_Price) ]

end
```

Here have I problems, because with this codes my model has no result and it doesnt run.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: can you be more specific with the error, please? If you just want to know the correct syntax for 'if thera buyer and seller in one patch' i suggest to write 'ask patches [if any? buyers-here and any? sellers-here [ ... do whatever you want ...]]', if the problem is one other, please be more specific!

Comment: More specific i can say that i have a problem with coding language, i dont know how I must code the processes and which commands i have to use. for example: my deal_Price has to be between the ownCosts of the seller and ownUtility of buyer (which are in the same patch). How can I code it?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a single question, but a bunch of questions in one. I'll try to say a few helpful things that address at least some of the issues you're facing, but in the future, it's really better if you ask specific questions and ask them separately. You'll know it's a good question if you can summarize it in a single sentence. If your summary ends up being "help me code this", it's probably not really a question.

`set buyer_Price buyer_Price < ownUtility` will set `buyer_price` to either `true` or `false`, depending on the result of the comparison. I don't think that's what you intended; you probably intended to set it to a number. I can't tell from your question what number you want, though. You write, “And this deal_Price has to be below ownUtility of the buyer and above of ownCosts of the seller”. Do you want a random number in that range, or what?

As for your `deal` procedure, dr_stein covered this in his or her comment, but, perhaps you want something like this:

```
to deal
  ask patches with [any? buyers-here and any? sellers-here] [
    ask buyers-here [
     set ownUtility ownUtility + (buyer_Price - deal_Price)
    ]
    ask sellers-here [
      set ownCosts ownCosts + (seller_Price - deal_Price)
    ]
  ]
end
```

that isn't complete because it doesn't contain any code which computes `deal_Price`, but hopefully you can supply that part yourself.

Finally, some more general advice. You may be trying to learn too much all at once by writing a big program all at once. Write a really small program; get it working; attempt to make a very small improvement to it, and get that working; and so on. If at any point you get stuck, come here, show your code, and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. secondly I want to say that I have to code a modell which was given me for my seminar topic and its not my choice. I have to code what is on my task.

Comment: I understand. But regardless of your final goal, the easiest and best way to build a large program is by small steps. Even expert programmers don't just sit down and write a whole bunch of code all at once. They proceed by small steps, as I'm suggesting.

Comment: sorry I thought i deleted my comment thats why i wrote all again to describe the situation of my model

Comment: When I write these code:
ask sellers [
   set seller_Price seller_Price > ownCosts ]
i get this error message:
The > operator can only be used on two numbers, two strings, or two agents of the same type, but not on a TRUE/FALSE and a number.
error while seller 26 running >
  called by procedure INTERACTION
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'GO'

what does it mean?

Comment: To ask a new question, open a new question. Don't tack comments onto an existing question.